# Vue Router Linking Children from Children

Tags: javascript, css, routes, vue.js, vue-router

I am currently trying to get this thing working with Vue Router.

The goal is:
If Nav#1 is clicked, a Component which includes another Router-Link with SubNav#1 preselected should appear.

I could get it to work in the way that if you click Nav#1, the Component with SubNav#1 with an already active class appeared. The problem is that the active class from Nav#1 is removed and it is not possible to navigate to Nav#2 or N#3. If I click on the Router-Link from Nav#2 or #3 nothing happens...

routes.js:

```
{ path: '/app', component: App,
    children: [
      { path: 'Nav#1', component: Nav#1_Content,
        children: [
          { path: 'SubNav#1', component: SubNav#1_Content},
          { path: 'SubNav#2', component: SubNav#2_Content}
        ]},
      { path: 'Nav#2', component: Nav#2_Content},
      { path: 'Nav#3', component: Nav#3_Content},
    ]}
```

+ custom linkActiveClass in new VueRouter instance.

Nav component:

```
<router-link to="Nav#1/SubNav#1">Nav #1</router-link>
<router-link to="Nav#2">Nav #2</router-link>
<router-link to="Nav#3">Nav #3</router-link>
```

Nav#1_Content component:

```
<template>
  <div>
   <nav>
     <router-link to="SubNav#1" tag="div">SubNav#1</router-link>
     <router-link to="SubNav#2" tag="div">SubNav#2</router-link>
   </nav>
   <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

[image]

Comment: I think the router links in the Nav#1 Component should have  `to="Nav#1/SubNav#1"` and `to="Nav#1/SubNav#2"`

Comment: Unfortunately not. If I apply this nothing works anymore.

Answer (score 2):

When you specify a value for the `to` prop on a `<router-link>` tag, you are specifying the exact path of the route to go to.

Since all of your example paths are under the `/app` root path, I'm not sure how you are getting any of these links to work.

That said, you need to get rid of the `#` signs in your route path definitions. When providing a path to Vue Router, it strips anything after the `#` sign and saves it as the `$route.hash` value.

So, use the full pathname in the `to` prop for your `<router-link>` tags and drop the `#` signs.

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gdh26Lqt/)